# Jenkins docker plugin with docker slaves

Tags: jenkins, docker

I'm running on docker 1.12.0, a docker image containing OpenJdk 8, Jenkins 1.609.3 and the following jenkins plugins:

jclouds-jenkins 2.8.1-1

token-macro 1.12.1

durable-task 1.12

docker-plugin 0.16.1

ssh-slaves 1.9

and another docker image as a jenkins slave.

When running a job that should execute on my docker jenkins slave, I have the following exception

```
SEVERE: Error in provisioning; template='DockerTemplate{configVersion=2, labelString='testslave', launcher=com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.launcher.DockerComputerSSHLauncher@5872b83f, remoteFsMapping='/home/jenkins', remoteFs='/home/jenkins', instanceCap=1, mode=EXCLUSIVE, retentionStrategy=com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.strategy.DockerOnceRetentionStrategy@6f59d98e, numExecutors=1, dockerTemplateBase=DockerTemplateBase{image=jenkins_slave}, removeVolumes=false, pullStrategy=PULL_LATEST}' for cloud='Local Dockerhost'
com.github.dockerjava.api.BadRequestException: {"message":"starting container with HostConfig was deprecated since v1.10 and removed in v1.12"}

    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.filter.ResponseStatusExceptionFilter.filter(ResponseStatusExceptionFilter.java:43)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:333)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:28)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:13)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.java:23)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:33)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.StartContainerCmdImpl.exec(StartContainerCmdImpl.java:53)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud.runContainer(DockerCloud.java:294)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud.provisionWithWait(DockerCloud.java:372)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud.access$000(DockerCloud.java:58)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud$1.call(DockerCloud.java:248)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud$1.call(DockerCloud.java:245)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Aug 18, 2016 12:22:32 PM hudson.slaves.NodeProvisioner$2 run
WARNING: Provisioned slave Image of jenkins_slave failed to launch
com.github.dockerjava.api.BadRequestException: {"message":"starting container with HostConfig was deprecated since v1.10 and removed in v1.12"}

    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.filter.ResponseStatusExceptionFilter.filter(ResponseStatusExceptionFilter.java:43)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:134)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientFilteringStages$ResponseFilterStage.apply(ClientFilteringStages.java:123)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.Stages.process(Stages.java:171)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.ClientRuntime.invoke(ClientRuntime.java:251)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:667)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$1.call(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:315)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:297)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.internal.Errors.process(Errors.java:228)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.process.internal.RequestScope.runInScope(RequestScope.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation.invoke(JerseyInvocation.java:664)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.method(JerseyInvocation.java:424)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.client.JerseyInvocation$Builder.post(JerseyInvocation.java:333)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:28)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.StartContainerCmdExec.execute(StartContainerCmdExec.java:13)
    at com.github.dockerjava.jaxrs.AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.exec(AbstrSyncDockerCmdExec.java:23)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.AbstrDockerCmd.exec(AbstrDockerCmd.java:33)
    at com.github.dockerjava.core.command.StartContainerCmdImpl.exec(StartContainerCmdImpl.java:53)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud.runContainer(DockerCloud.java:294)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud.provisionWithWait(DockerCloud.java:372)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud.access$000(DockerCloud.java:58)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud$1.call(DockerCloud.java:248)
    at com.nirima.jenkins.plugins.docker.DockerCloud$1.call(DockerCloud.java:245)
    at jenkins.util.ContextResettingExecutorService$2.call(ContextResettingExecutorService.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Similar question . Please refer. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616906/jenkins-trigger-on-demand-slaves-in-dockers/38639548#38639548

Comment: I did all this configuration already, but I have the exception thrown.

Comment: pls verify once whether u restricted the slave execution (label - given in global config ) in job. & retention strategy & executors. above mentioned is a working solution. docker version 1.10

Comment: I checked many times.  I have docker v1.12.0 and cannot change it.

Comment: I tried the same but with docker v1.9.1 and it is working.  So the problem is with the plugins and docker v1.12.