# How to create nodes in Jenkins automatically?

Tags: docker, jenkins, docker-compose, jenkins-pipeline, devops

I have a jenkins pipeline. If there is a command for Jenkinsfile scripts that can create build nodes dynamically. So several builds for more than one commit to a project can run in parallel.

I would like to elaborate more in details. Already I have configured Nodes and Executers in my Jenkins configuration. But as of now node is manually created I want to create it dynamically through Jenkinsfile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jenkins trigger on-demand slaves in dockers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38616906/jenkins-trigger-on-demand-slaves-in-dockers)

Comment: @Stefano ..... I would like to elaborate more in details. Already I have configured Nodes and Executers in my Jenkins configuration. But as of now node is manually created I want to create it dynamically through Jenkinsfile.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm following... would you like to have the nodes to generate new nodes during the build or would you like to have the jenkins to automatically generate the node when a build is requested?

Comment: @Stefano ..... Exactly, I would  like to have the Jenkins to automatically generate the node when a build is requested?

Comment: the answer to the question I mentioned in the first comment explains exactly how to achieve that. just follow those steps and you're good to go.

Comment: @Stefano ... Is there any way to create it from Jenkins file(groovy script)?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200229/discussion-between-shanmukh-and-stefano).